# Add “Select All” to custom taxonomy in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I originally posted this in the WordPress Stack Exchange and it was recommended to post it here as it's likely a javascript solution.

What I'm looking to do is to add a "Select All" to a custom taxonomy for my custom post type in WordPress. A project I'm working on requires the option to be able to select all of the taxonomy terms. While I could go through and manually click each term, it becomes quite cumbersome when I have several hundred terms.

I haven't tried anything yet, as I'm not sure how to go about it...how would I go about doing this? Is it something that would be added to `functions.php` or something else?

Comment: From where do you want to select all ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera This is in the dashboard while editing a particular post of my custom post type. It would be a button or something that is in the native taxonomy term box.

Comment: @SheikhHeera it would also be great to add this option to the "Bulk Edit" of the custom post type